# scala variables initialization

Tags: scala, function, variables, scope

```
package Controls

object TestBreak extends App {

  def values = {
    x1 = x
    y1 = y
  }

  val (x, y) = (1, 2)

  values

  var (x1, y1) = (2, 3)

  println((x, y))

  println((x1, y1))

}
```

I could see here, the program is Executing successfully without any error.

When i call method **values** ,even before the intialization of variables x1,y1,..

1. How does scala handles this case ?
2. How compilation of code is taking palce ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## App extends DelayedInit

As `App` extends `DelayedInit` and `Main` extends `App`. Code in the `Main` constructor executes as part of delayed init. Before jumping into how delayed init works, Lets see the differnce between constructor variable declaration and method variable declaration.

```
scala> class A {
     | def a(): Unit = { println(b) }
     | val b = 1
     | }
defined class A
```

In the above example `b` is declared later and function `a()` is declared first. As it the constructor of the class Compiler accepts it.

```
scala> def x: Int = {
     | def y: Int = z
     | val z = 1
     | y
     | }
<console>:12: error: forward reference extends over definition of value z
       def y: Int = z
                ^
```

In the above case compiler complains saying that its a forward reference.

## Delayed Init is deprecated

Classes and objects (but note, not traits) inheriting the DelayedInit marker trait will have their initialization code rewritten as follows: code becomes delayedInit(code).

Initialization code comprises all statements and all value definitions that are executed during initialization.

Example:

```
trait Helper extends DelayedInit {
  def delayedInit(body: => Unit) = {
    println("dummy text, printed before initialization of C")
    body // evaluates the initialization code of C
  }
}

class C extends Helper {
  println("this is the initialization code of C")
}

object Test extends App {
  val c = new C
}
```

Should result in the following being printed:

```
dummy text, printed before initialization of C
this is the initialization code of C
```

Comment: read more about delayed init from here (http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/DelayedInit.html)